# Error al instalar clarifai could not find a version that satisfies the requirement clarifai.rest (from versions:)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Estoy tratando de instalar un módulo llamado clarifai, usando pip install clarifai, y me tira el siguiente error

> could not find a version that satisfies the requirement clarifai.rest
>   (from versions:)

por lo que he leído otros lo han instalado usando pip y les funciona desde la línea de comandos pero no al importarlo, a mi no me lo instala directamente. Cómo se puede solucionar?

Comment: Pablo yo al menos no puedo reproducir el problema, en un entorno virtual con Python 2.7.14 y `pip` **actualizado** no tengo ningún problema para instalar (mediante `python -m pip install clarifai`) ni para importar de `clarifai.rest`  p.e `from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp`
. No se si será de ayuda pero sería bueno que colocaras la traza completa del error si es posible, la versión de pip y de Python también pueden ayudar. Un saludo.

Comment: se soluciono actualizando el pip, si quieres publicalo como respuesta y te lo apruebo (ya que sugeriste que podia ser eso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intente actualizar pip de la siguiente manera:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Tu problema parece estar relacionado con la desactivación reciente de TLS para pip. Vea [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703) respuesta para más detalles.